# Optimize Native Message Host in Java for larger Strings

Tags: java, performance, chrome-native-messaging

I am using Chrome's Native Messaging API to pass data to my host in Java. The data is a 512 KB long String encoded in Base64. The problem is that the Host is taking too long to read the data from the standard input.
I read the following post: [Very Slow to pass "large" amount of data from Chrome Extension to Host (written in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653624/very-slow-to-pass-large-amount-of-data-from-chrome-extension-to-host-written) and I understand that the problem is how I read the bytes but I was’nt able to adapt that code to java so far.

The code of my host is:

```
try {

    // hilo principal de la aplicacion
    while(true){

        int length = 0;
        String input = "";
        String output = "";
        String outputType = "";

        // cargamos la logitud de caracteres en bytes
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        System.in.read(bytes, 0, 4);
        length = getInt(bytes);

        // cargamos los datos enviados
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        System.in.read(data, 0, length);

        if (length == 0){
            // si no recibimos datos ponemos un sleep para no comer todos los recursos del equipo
            Thread.sleep(50);
            break;
        }else{
            // Loop getchar to pull in the message until we reach the total length provided.
            for (int i=0; i < length; i++){

                input += (char) data[i];
            }

            // leemos el texto enviado del dato en JSON
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(input);
            String texto = obj.getString("text");

            System.err.write(("TEXT: " + texto).getBytes());

            // creamos el mensaje de respuesta y lo enviamos
            String respuesta = "{\"type\":\"TEST\", \"text\":\"" + texto + "\"}";

            System.out.write(getBytes(respuesta.length()));
            System.out.write(respuesta.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need help to adapt the code of my host in java to read the message quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do most of that, and without the bugs, with `DataInputStream.readInt()` and `.readFully()`. If you're on an Intel you will need to rearrange the int for native byte order, as this reads network byte order.
- Put a `BufferedInputStream` between that and `System.in`: that will solve the major performance problem.
- Solve the other performance problem via `new String(data,...)` instead of the appending loop.
- It's hard to see why they would send you a zero length, but if they do, sleeping isn't going to accomplish anything except wasting time. Remove that.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it works great now. the code is in the following [link](http://pastebin.com/seCcZqK4) if anyone needs it.