# How to automate an active instance of Google Chrome in C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver, rpa

Usually I'm using Selenium to automate Chrome but in this case I need to connect to the already opened browser. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Selenium allows only creating a new instance of Chrome. In IE I'm using SHDocVw and mshtml libraries, but I'm wondering if there are any libriaries to connect Chrome? I'm not writing an app, it's just a script, like RPA (Robotic Process Automation).

Comment: Maybe with native messaging? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880709/c-sharp-native-host-with-chrome-native-messaging