# Can't get C# host app to launch from Chrome Extension

Tags: c#, json, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I'm following this post to try to setup a C# native messaging host.
[C# native host with Chrome Native Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880709/c-sharp-native-host-with-chrome-native-messaging)

I've got my sample running where I an launch Calc.exe from a bat file, like this:

**host.json**

```
{
  "name": "tsetools",
  "description": "TSE tools for Chrome",
  "path": "tse-host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://ddemkjpofammommjpcmkhpajoccdjcdg/"
  ]
}
```

**tse-host.bat**

```
@echo off
CD C:\Windows\System32
start calc.exe
```

The above works fine & launches Calc.exe

But if I change **host.json** to the following:

```
{
  "name": "tsetools",
  "description": "TSE tools for Chrome",
  "path": "TSEChromeHost.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://jahdheagjlkdjcoeibobaphodgpgpacc/"
  ]
}
```

I never see "TSEChromeHost.exe" get launched in the task manager. I've built the C# code from the post above without any errors & can lunch it manually. I have "TSEChromeHost.exe" in the same folder as my "host.json" file.

Any ideas as what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is that `TSEChromeHost.exe` can't be located.
Try this:

You need to change `tse-host.bat` file like this ( you need to change your working directory to dir where `TSEChromeHost.exe` is located )

```
@echo off
Pushd D:\SomeDir 
start TSEChromeHost.exe
```

Change `D:\SomeDir` to driectory where `TSEChromeHost.exe` file is located.

And Also Set `path` key in `host.json` file like this: ( as in first example )

```
"path": "tse-host.bat"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It now launching my "TSEChromeHost.exe", but it doesn't seem to be receiving any messages. I thought if "host.json" was calling a .bat file, that the messages would also be sent to the .bat file & of course that doesn't work. So how do I get the message to be sent to "TSEChromeHost.exe"?

Comment: This post shows calling the native host app directly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219144/native-messaging-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify full path to your TSEChromeHost.exe. On Linux and OSX the path must be absolute. On Windows it can be relative to the directory in which the manifest file is located. (See [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging))

```
"path": "Full_path_to_TSEChromeHost.exe"
```

eg

```
"path": "C:\\TestFolder\\TSEChromeHost.exe"
```